# Install Vintage Ceiling Light Fixture

Tags: ceiling, light

We purchased a vintage ceiling light fixture in Europe and I’m trying to figure out how to mount it.

I’ve attached photos below.

It seems to have a sort of hickey attached to the end of the post with a screw for grounding. I’m not clear on how this would attach to the electrical box in the ceiling. I can how I could pass the post through the ceiling mount hole and attach it with the hickey, but then it seems like all that is holding the lamp to the mount is the tiny screw crimping the hickey to the post.  The post has no threads.

Any thoughts?

What other hardware do I need?

Many thanks!

[image][image]

Comment: Are you sure that's a setscrew and not going into a hole in the hickey?  It looks bottomed out, and setscrews shouldn't bottom out...

Comment: @Harper : I believe they mean the screw on the upper right.

Comment: @MacHeartDoc  i tried to edit this sentence *"I can how I could pass the post through the ceiling mount hole and attach it with the hickey, but then it seems like all that is holding the lamp to the mount is the tiny screw crimping the hickey to the post."*   but i can not wrap my head around what is your are trying to say. Question or statement ?

Comment: Can you disconnect the Post from the where it attaches to the fixture ?

Comment: Correct - the screw in the upper right is the ground. I’m sorry I wasn’t clearer. I can unscrew the Hickey from the pole and then could pass the pole through the ceiling mount and reattach the hickey around the pole and mount. Just seems flimsy.

Comment: And I could probably detach the pole from the fixture. Looks like it’s threaded in and there’s a nut securing it.

Comment: If it’s threaded in then you could replace it with a threaded post as in modern fixtures

Comment: If that little black screw threads in, then that makes perfect sense.  That is probably the intended Euro mounting method.  Have you tried taking it into a lighting supply house and see what they say?

Comment: The little black screw does thread in to the hickey, but it just kinda crimps the post and there's an indentation where it grabs it, but no hole in the post.  I'd prefer not to replace the original post, but if I did where on-line could I find it and what would I search for?  I'll see if I can find a good lighting supply house too and ask.

Comment: If down rod comes off can threads be cut in ?  Or change down rod all together and maybe able to get parts and mount like a new fan.  Being from  Europe will it work in the  USA?